# Installing Github Flavored Markdown in Roadkill Wiki

Tags: github-flavored-markdown, roadkill-wiki

I would like to use the Github Flavored Markdown found [here](https://github.com/gitlabhq/markup#markups) on my employer's internal Roadkill wiki (which I manage so I have permissions to install plugins).

Can someone explain how I go about adding this to our Roadkill wiki?  I cannot find anything on Google about adding it to Roadkill.

A few questions I have upfront:

- I see instruction on adding it on the webpage using 'gem'put don't know what 'gem' is.  Is this a Ruby thing?
- Do I need to download the entire source code and compile before using on Roadkill?  If so what language is it using?